# Multidimensional Array Unwrapping an Optional

Tags: ios, arrays, multidimensional-array, swift2

so I'm having this problem where I can't unwrap an optional for outputting it into the label, I've even tried just printing it in the console and it still gives me an optional

The code and array are in different files.

Code It's in a VC:

```
for var i = 0; i < stateName.count; i++ {
        if tax.state == stateName[i][0] {
            stateName[i][1] = Double(taxNumb.text!)!
            print(stateName[i][1])
            output.text = String(stateName[i][1])
        }
    }
```

Array Code I made this in an empty swift file:

```
var tax : Taxes? = nil

var stateName = [
  ["AK - Alaska", tax?.alaska!],
  ["AL - Alabama", tax?.alabama!],
  ["AR - Arkansas", tax?.arkansas!],
  ["AZ - Arizona", tax?.arizona!],
  ["CA - California", tax?.california!]
]
```

Comment: Try using `output.text = "\(stateName[i]?[1] ?? "")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment to your previous question use the "Nil Coalescing" `??` operator:

```
output.text = String(stateName[i][1] ?? "not set")
```

Or using the alternate swift String magic

```
output.text = "\(stateName[i][1] ?? "not set")"
```

The operator returns the first value if it not nil, otherwise it returns the second value.

Comment: It still outputs Optional() to the label

Comment: @Karpisdiem I cannot reproduce that issue, the code works perfectly for me

Comment: is it because I have that array in a separate swift file and I didn't properly import it into the view controller where I'm printing the code for the for loop?

Comment: @Karpisdiem using which of the above two methods do you get what exact output?

Comment: using both methods I get Optional(number), but having the array in the same view Controller I don't get that optional

Comment: okay, how do you get the array? is the array itself some optional again?

Comment: the array it's self is an optional

Comment: can you please show how the array is currently delcared?

Comment: I posted it up there ^^

Comment: well, that array is not an optional, it just is an array. Maybe show the `Taxes` class as well.

Comment: I didn't put it in a class maybe thats the problem